# Difference between Sequential and Parallel executing in $q

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular-promise, q, angularjs-q

**In both of at the time of execution of an asynchronic operation only.**

---

> - But how the `$q` handle for this is a Sequential call or Parallel call on runtime?
> - and let me brief explanation about the Difference between Sequential and Parallel executing in angular $q

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parallel Execution is something in which it doesn't wait for the previous process to be done,and Sequential is something in which process are executed one after another.

$q service is used for asynchronous call (parallel execution | promise handling),by default it does parallel execution,it does not have support for sequential execution.
If you want a sequential execution you have to handle it manually, wheich means after getting response from one call you make another call.

```
var promise;
promise.then(fun(){
   var promise;
   promise.then(fun(){
   })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

To execute promises in parallel:

```
var promise1 = promiseAPI(params1);
var promise2 = promiseAPI(params2);

var promise1and2 = $q.all([promise1, promise2]);
```

To execute promises sequentually, **return** the next promise to the first promise success handler:

```
var promise1 = promiseAPI(params1);

var promise1then2 = promise1.then(function() {
    var promise2 = promiseAPI(params2);
    //return to chain
    return promise2;
});
```

*Because calling the `.then` method of a promise returns a new derived promise, it is easily possible to create a chain of promises. It is possible to create chains of any length and **since a promise can be resolved with another promise** (which will defer its resolution further), it is possible to pause/defer resolution of the promises at any point in the chain.*

-- [AngularJS $q Service API Reference -- Chaining Promises](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#chaining-promises).